When will 'vehicle-to-grid' be available?
There is already a thread on this SE but it's now 5 years old and has not really been updated.
I'm thinking of adding solar panels and a battery to my house (see my other question about this) but I have also just purchased an electric car which has Vehicle-to-load output. The cost per kWh for a car battery is far less than that quoted for a domestic battery, so it would make sense for me to use the car battery for storage rather than buying an additional one.
Why is V-to-grid technology taking so long to come to fruition?

I don't know what your domestic battery is. However, I suspect today the cheapest way to create a large domestic battery is to buy a huge number of 12V Chinese LiFePO4 batteries, connect them in series/parallel to have a 48V system, and then add three single phase 48V inverter-chargers to create a 3-phase system that can charge and discharge the battery system.
An electric car probably won't be cheaper. But if your comparison point is something like a Tesla Powerwall, stop! Tesla Powerwall uses NMC batteries which are less durable than LiFePO4 batteries, and is a unit where you can't replace the batteries and inverters separately.
Tesla electric cars use NCA batteries which are even less durable than NMC batteries. Tesla PowerWalls use NMC batteries which may be somewhat acceptable for grid energy storage unless you realize that LiFePO4 batteries are an even better option.
Typically, cars don't include 3-phase inverters. The idea is that if you want bidirectional charging, you have a DC bidirectional charger that contains an inverter to create 3-phase power out of the DC the battery provides.
The trouble is, such bidirectional charger aren't generally available.
If you're planning to use NCA EV batteries for grid energy storage, you'd better avoid the full charge and empty charge operating points, and limit your usage of the state of charge to be between 20% - 80% for example.
An included single-phase inverter isn't of any help to provide grid energy storage. It's only for vehicle-to-load, not for vehicle-to-grid. Vehicle-to-grid requires a 3-phase inverter.

I doubt they arrive. There are many demonstration projects, and various products, but I do not think they will get a significant number.
There are several reasons: one is about who want the benefit: the car owner or the utility company? Finding a right share is difficult, and initial push was from utilities, so the problem on their side to find a good compromise (and still convenient for them) delayed everything, and now I think few of them are pushing them, mostly where they have some storage problem.
Also batteries are becoming cheaper, and more available. For a car you may want mileages, so new batteries (and so not used for other uses), but for your home you can uses old car batteries (weight is not important, so if they carry just half energy, but they cost a fraction of new, why not using them?)
Also the user case has some problem. Should we store midday energy (sun) for the night? But now (in many places) night electricity is cheap. And car may not be at home. And electric car are convenient if you do mileages (so for everyday commuting).
So the benefit and demand is not great. But if you look carefully, you see that various chargers can do also the "uncharging". Some less choice, but you get it, and it could be a good solution if you already have the electrical setup to accept electricity from batteries, and they you handle it as energy from a solar panel. (But electric utilities may not agree: they may have a target on renewable, and your energy should not be considered a green-washing (in: random energy: out: like solar), and so maybe some less acceptance on their side. But if you use your own batteries it is fine.
